# Scala Worksheet IntelliJ -- Internal Error

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I'm having issues with getting Scala Worksheets to work in IntelliJ.

I've already reinstalled JDK 8 and installed the latest SBT version.

The setting in IntelliJ seem fine to me, but I might missed something. Anyone knows how to resolve these issues?

[image: Internal error]

> Internal error: Could not initialize class com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinBase$FILETIME
>       org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.ClientEventProcessor.process(ClientEventProcessor.scala:22)
>       org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner.handle(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:47)
>       org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner.handle$(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:37)
>       org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.compiler.RemoteServerRunner.handle(RemoteServerRunner.scala:16)
>       org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner.$anonfun$send$5(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:30)
>       org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner.$anonfun$send$5$adapted(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:29)
>       org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.package$.using(package.scala:21)
>       org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner.$anonfun$send$3(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:29)
>       org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner.$anonfun$send$3$adapted(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:25)
>       org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.package$.using(package.scala:21)
>       org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner.$anonfun$send$2(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:25)
>       org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner.$anonfun$send$2$adapted(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:24)
>       org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.package$.using(package.scala:21)
>       org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner.send(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:24)
>       org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner.send$(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:22)
>       org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.compiler.RemoteServerRunner.send(RemoteServerRunner.scala:16)
>       org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.compiler.RemoteServerRunner$$anon$1.$anonfun$run$1(RemoteServerRunner.scala:36)
>       scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:156)
>       org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.compiler.RemoteServerRunner$$anon$1.run(RemoteServerRunner.scala:32)
>       org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.worksheet.server.RemoteServerConnector.compileAndRun(RemoteServerConnector.scala:111)
>       org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.worksheet.processor.WorksheetCompiler$$anon$3.run(WorksheetCompiler.scala:66)
>       com.intellij.compiler.progress.CompilerTask.run(CompilerTask.java:192)
>       com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:750)
>       com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
>       com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:580)
>       com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:525)
>       com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:85)
>       com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:144)
>       com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$4.run(CoreProgressManager.java:395)
>       com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:305)
>       java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Settings IntelliJ:
[image: Settings for intelliJ]

Comment: Can you try killing the sbt-server which runs and then run the work sheet?

Comment: Do you mean the compile server?

Comment: Correct @Hespen

Comment: It does seem to run, but the problem is, there is no output

Comment: There is this arrow in the top corner, which keeps on spinning: https://gyazo.com/ee59b56bbc099b39639d34060420cbda

Comment: It appears to run but there is no output even for intellij 2019 the latest at the moment. It works if I swich run type to Plain rather than REPL